# What heathkit data do I have to write to contribute to the green exercise ring of the activity app?

Tags: ios, healthkit

What data does an app have to write to the health store so that the data is counted to the green exercise ring of the activity app?

Is there a a threshold and how do I figure out that threshold?

So for example active burned calories / second > threshold for at least n seconds would be my guess, but I don't find the information.

**Edit**
iOS 9.3/watchOS 2.2 adds functionality for the exercise ring but not writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for an app to contribute to the Exercise ring.  The minutes counted in that ring are based exclusively off the user's level of activity as measured by the algorithms built into watchOS.

Comment: So there is no way for a third party to build hardware that contributes data to the exercise ring?

Comment: Not at this time.  You should file a radar with Apple if you'd like that capability to be exposed to developers.

Comment: @Allan This answer is quite old and currently, I have the same question so there is no way for an app to contribute to the Exercise ring?

Comment: Apps can contribute to the Exercise ring by recording a live workout on watchOS or by saving a workout on iOS. There is no other way to influence the ring.